# Expand dataframe shows `x` is not a regular sequence error

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, expand

I am having trouble expanding the following dataframe.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
options(digits = 10)
library(readxl)
```

The following is the dataframe

```
df1= data.frame("ID"=c("A", "A", "A", "A", 'A', "B", 'B', "B", "B", 'B'), 
"A_Frequency"=c(1,2,3,4,5, 2.788,3.122,4,4.888,6), 
"A_Axis"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12),
"B_Frequency"=c(2,3,4,6,7, 2.677, 2.977, 3.877, 4.788, 7), 
"B_Axis"=c(1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,14))
```

We now create df2 as follows

```
df2<- df1 %>%group_by(ID) %>%rowwise() %>% mutate(Sfreq = 
 min(na.omit(c(A_Frequency, B_Frequency))))
```

Next I am expanding the dataframe as follows

```
df3<- df2%>%group_by(ID)%>%expand(Sfreq=full_seq(Sfreq,0.001))
```

I am getting the following error

> Error: `x` is not a regular sequence.

I have tried changing the expand function as follows

```
 df3<- df2%>%group_by(ID)%>%expand(Sfreq=full_seq(Sfreq,0.000001))
```

However, this either doesn't work or on occasion slows the code. Is there an alternate way to achieve the same.

Comment: If `0.001` is your tolerance you need to specify it in the arguments (`full_seq(..., tol = 0.001)`). But then the period will be missing

Comment: I dont quite follow sir. Can you elaborate

Comment: You say `full_freq(Sfreq, 0.001)`. What is `0.001` supposed to represent?

Comment: It reprsents the steps by which variable Sfreq will be expnded. thus, between 5, 6, there will be 5.001, 5.002, 5.003 etc

Comment: ahhh...ok. I think you want `complete`. Try `ungroup(df2) %>% group_by(ID) %>% complete(Sfreq = seq(min(Sfreq), max(Sfreq), by = 0.001))`

Comment: Thank you Sir. This seems to do the trick. is there a dplyr tutorial that will help. Its useful, but am still unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189936/discussion-between-marcia-akshaya-leo-and-sotos).

Comment: Of course. There are tons of info out there. Just google 'tidyverse' and you will get a bunch of results. However, I suggest you learn base R first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you need `complete`, not `expand`. Note that you first need to `ungroup` your data frame since it is grouped rowwise.

```
library(tidyverse)

ungroup(df2) %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 complete(Sfreq = seq(min(Sfreq), max(Sfreq), by = 0.001))
```